# How to use @angular/universal with Leaflet?

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-universal

Is it possible to use Leaflet with angular/universal? How can I avoid to build Leaflet within server?

After `npm run build:prod` dist folder is generated. But when I run `node server.js` I get following error:

> var requestFn = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
>   getPrefixed('RequestAnimationFrame') || timeoutDefer; Window is not
>   defined.

Comment: check  platform  id  and if it's  server   don't render leaflet component using  `*ngIf`  for example

Answer (score 9):

After hours of searching I found a solution. You need to use Leaflet with custom service.

**leaflet.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class LeafletService {

  public L = null;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      this.L = require('leaflet');
    }
  }

}
```

**map.component.ts**

```
constructor (
    private leafletService: LeafletService
) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    this.leafletService.L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    ...
}
```

There is also an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/NickToony/universal-starter-leaflet-example)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by mocking `window`, `navigator` and `document` with [Mock Browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser)

Just install the mock browser pacakge 
 `npm i mock-browser`

And add the following code to your `server.ts`:

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();


global['window'] = mock.getWindow();
global['document'] = mock.getDocument();
global['navigator'] = mock.getNavigator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when leaflet is just sitting there in your code, it will still trigger the error. For example:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";

function getLatLng () {
    return new L.LatLng(0, 0);
}

console.log("Hi, there");
```

This snippet will not run in NodeJS due to the error mentioned above.

While mocking browser api's server-side could work for some cases, the best way is to simply avoid Leaflet loading on server. This can be done by lazy-loading a module and component (tested in Angular 13):

### Step 1. Create a module and a component

Create a module containing a component for your map. You can safely use leaflet or other map-related libraries here.

Add a static reference to the component in your module so you can access it after lazy-loading the module:

```
export class MyFeatureMapModule {
    static MyFeatureMapComponent = MyFeatureMapComponent;
}
```

IMPORTANT: Don't make any direct references/imports to this module or any of its components!!

### Step 2. Create a placeholder/loader component

Create a component and add it to your page. The component must follow these rules:

- It must not have any logic or references related to Leaflet or any other map library.
- It must contain the code to lazy-load the module defined in step 1 (see example below)
- It must use a strategy to only lazy-load the module in the browser
- It must have a loading state for bonus points!

Example:

```
 @Component({
    selector: "app-my-feature-map-loader",
    template: `
        <ng-container #container></ng-container>
        <div *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class MyFeatureMapLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild("container", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

    loading = true;

    constructor (@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object) {
    }

    ngOnInit (): void {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            import("../../../my-feature-map/my-feature-map.module").then(({ MyFeatureMapModule }) => {
                const componentRef = this.mapContainer.createComponent(MyFeatureMapModule.MyFeatureMapComponent);
                const componentInstance = componentRef.instance;
                componentInstance.load.subscribe((map) => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
            });
        }
    }

}
```

This example will automatically load the map immediately (when in browser). Depending on the scenario, you could also use the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) to load the map as soon as it becomes visible in the viewport (ie. while scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you are getting you should need to add the platform browser check if you are rendering your application from server, because keywords like window, document etc are not available on server. so add checks like this -

```
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

export class XYZ implements OnInit{
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: any) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
            // use window, document keywords here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried it, but error remains. I also tried remove map and build project without it, but it remains. Can it be caused by node_modules/leaflet?

Comment: probably you are using some third party plugin which doesn't support SSR, that could be one of the reason of error you are getting.

Comment: I am going to check it. Is it possible to explicitly forbidden some of node modules to generate within server side?

Comment: not sure about that, but yes you can load some packages conditionally as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use leaflet in your component via custom leaflet service.

**leaflet.component.ts**

```
export class LeafletMapComponent implements OnInit {
  public L = null;  
  public latLng= null;
  public marker = null;

  constructor(public leafletMapService: LeafletMapService, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      this.L = require('leaflet');
      require('leaflet-draw');
      require('leaflet.markercluster');
      this.latLng = this.L.latLng;
      this.marker = this.L.marker;
    }
   }
}
```

I added here leaflet-draw and leaflet-markercluster libraries additionaly.Please check your code and functions if you have L or latLng or marker and add this in front of them.

**leafletMap.service.ts**

```
export class LeafletMapService {

  public L = null;
  public latLng= null;
  public marker = null;

  public latitude: number = 41.03642025806215;
  public longitude: number = 28.9864390611855;
  public centerMarker;
  markerClusterGroup: any;
  mainLayerGeoJson;
  public map;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      this.L = require('leaflet');
      require('leaflet-draw');
      require('leaflet.markercluster');
      this.latLng = this.L.latLng;
      this.marker = this.L.marker;
    }
   }
```

I added here leaflet-draw and leaflet-markercluster libraries additionaly.Please check your code and functions if you have L or latLng or marker and add this in front of them.