# Error in Angular Server-Side Rendering (SSR) with ngx-leaflet: "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I am encountering an issue with Angular v17 Server-Side Rendering (SSR) and the ngx-leaflet library in my Angular application. When trying to run the application in an SSR environment, I am getting the following error after build and before prerendering :

> "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

I know it's because window isn't accessible on the server side, but I don't use the window object, I think it's due to the use of a function in the library that uses window.

Any idea how to find where to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@if(showLeaflet) {
<div style="height: 300px;"
     leaflet 
     [leafletOptions]="options">
</div>
}
```

Code-behind

```
platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
showLeaflet = false;
//...
ngOnInit() {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    showLeaflet  = true;
  }
}
```

---

Generally,

If you are inside a component, use [`afterNextRender`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterRenderPhase)

```
afterNextRender(() => {
  //access window, localStorage, sessionStorage
}, {phase: AfterRenderPhase.Read});
```

If not(when in services, guards, etc...) use [`isPlatformBrowser`](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser)

```
platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
// ...
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  //access window, localStorage, sessionStorage
}
```

Comment: I wrap all my leaflet code with *ngIf="showLeaflet()" but the error still here :/
  private platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  showLeaflet = computed(() => isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId));

Comment: It works when i serve my ssr app but not when i want to use prerendering

Comment: @Tim: read this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308035/17447