# angular universal import leaflet extension plugin

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-universal

In the development state, I can load the main plugin(ex:[leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/)) and its extension plugin(ex: [MovingMarker.js](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker)) in sequence, and they all work normally.

For example:

```
import { FeatureGroup, featureGroup, Map} from 'leaflet';
declare var L: any;
import "src/assets/js/Leaflet.MovingMarker/MovingMarker.js";
```

But when running universal, various `xxx is not defined` conditions began to appear.

At first, there will be various `not defined` errors in the `leaflet`.
But this problem can be solved by this [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214726/5706510).
It can avoid the three `xxx is not defined` of`'window'` `'document'` `'navigator'`.

But when loading `MovingMarker`, there will be a dependency problem. It is attached to the object `L`.

Error message:

```
ver.js:280163
L.interpolatePosition = function(p1, p2, duration, t) {
^

ReferenceError: L is not defined
    at Object../src/assets/js/Leaflet.MovingMarker/MovingMarker.js
```

Comment: import * as L from 'leaflet';// try to use import like this <<< and remove L: any;

Comment: I tried it, and the error message `"425:34-error TS2339: Property'movingMarker' does not exist on type'typeof Marker'." `appears during binding.

Comment: Could you check this example, I noticed there is a MovingMarker.js on it https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker

Comment: you could include the MovingMarker.js in the assets folder and add reference it

Comment: Do you know `angular universal `(SSR)? MovingMarker can import, but it cannot be successfully executed in SSR.